# Finding the maximum digit in an integer

Tags: python

I want to find the max value of a number that consists of
for example:

- 123 (max digit is 3)
- 346 (max digit is 6)

like that.

I know how to find among several numbers:

```
numbers = [9, 34, 11, -4, 27]

# find the maximum number
max_number = max(numbers)
print(max_number)
```

But I can't find in a number.

Comment: Maybe try `max(str(number))` to get the highest digit of a single number as a string

Answer (score -2):

#this is just an example for maximum numbers

numb = [11,21,211,5,-7,0]
temp = max(numb)
print(temp)